# React Native zIndex does not work for view

Tags: android, react-native, z-index, react-native-flatlist

I want to arrange the pictures absolutely in a flatlist. at the same time, the first picture should be higher in zIndex.
as a result, zIndex is not applied to me and the pictures are arranged in the order of rendering.

It turns out that the subsequent elements of the flatlist are superimposed on each other

[image]

What could be the problem?

my code.

```
const data = [
  {
    key: '0',
    image:
      'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1589182373726-e4f658ab50f0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=687&q=80',
    name: 'Everest',
  },
  ...
];

export default function TravelUpList({navigation}) {
  return (
    <FlatList
      data={data}
      keyExtractor={item => item.key}
      scrollEnabled={false}
      contentContainerStyle={{
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
      }}
      CellRendererComponent={({index, item, children, style, ...props}) => {
        const newStyle = [
          style,
          {
            zIndex: data.length - index, //this line does not work
            left: -IMAGE_WIDTH / 2,
            top: -IMAGE_HEIGHT / 2,
          },
        ];
        return (
          <View index={index} {...props} style={newStyle}>
            {children}
          </View>
        );
      }}
      renderItem={({item, index}) => {
        return (
          <View style={{position: 'absolute']}}>
            <Image source={{uri: item.image}} style={styles.image} />
            <View
              style={{position: 'absolute', bottom: 0, padding: 20}}>
              <Text style={styles.name} numberOfLines={1} adjustsFontSizeToFit>
                {item.name}
              </Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        );
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

solved the problem by adding the removeClippedSubviews={false} parameter to
the flatlist. Now everything is displayed beautifully.

[image]